# Basic java recursion

Tags: java, recursion

Can someone please explain this to me.

```
public int bunnyEars(int bunnies) {
   if(bunnies == 0) {
       return 0;
   }
   return 2 + bunnyEars(bunnies - 1);
}
```

It seem to me if bunnies equals 2 the the answer
Would be 3 not 4. Even though I know the answer should be 4.

Comment: The only possible things that could be added together are the 0 in the first return, and the 2 in the second. How would you get an odd number?

Comment: Often I find it useful to take up pencil and paper when when trying to figure something like this out (This is not meant to be a snarky comment; I'm being completely serious).

Comment: ^ That's not snarky at all.  It's a great way to learn/understand what's happening.  You could also just add a couple print statements to unravel all mystery.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can unroll the recursion by hand to verify that it does indeed add 2 ears for every bunny

```
bunnyEars(2) => 2 + bunnyEars(1) => 2 + (2 + bunnyEars(0)) => 2 + (2 + 0) => 4
```

Answer (score 3):

```
bunnyEars(2) == 2 + bunnyEars(1) ==
2 + (2 + bunnyEars(0)) == 2 + (2 + 0) == 4
```